# Firebase Post Request, getting Missmatch Sender ID, Where to put Sender Id in Request?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to create a post request for sending firebase push notifications (trying on postman) and I am getting MismatchSenderId:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 4548549053367743061,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have sender id from firebase console:
[image: Firebase Console Project settings screnshot]
But i dont know how to put it in my starting request which is like this:

```
{

    "to": "************************ server Key from firebase project settings",
  "message":{
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    
  }
}
```

And headers look like this:

[image: Postman Headers section]